# Boruta package in R adding ` ` around column names in character vector saved

Tags: r, vector, character

I am using boruta package to extract the useful predictors.But when I save the final predictors,they are saved in a character vector and the predictor names have `` added.
Predictor names are saved as "`open read`","`nap close`" with

I want to subset my original date set so that i have a new dataframe with just selected predictors but the names dont match due to added .How do i get rid of these?

Comment: That will always happen if you have spaces or other reserved characters in your column names.  Perhaps convert them to valid names with `make.names()` first.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This really helps.